# Где посмотреть документацию для Henooh Device Emulator?

Tags: c#

Вот ссылка на эмулятор https://www.henooh.com/Portfolio/HenoohDeviceEmulator, ссылка на документацию https://www.henooh.com/Documentation не работает.

**Мне нужно посмотреть как написать отправку нажатия клавиши F1, и сочетания клавиш alt+1**

Comment: https://www.henooh.com/Home/Contact

Answer (score 0):

Вот так сделал

Подключение:

```
using Henooh.DeviceEmulator;
using Henooh.DeviceEmulator.Native;
```

Нажатие клавиши 1:

```
  KeyboardController kb = new KeyboardController();
  kb.Type(VirtualKeyCode.VK_1);
```